# Inverting an ARMA model on a time series to obtain residuals in R

Tags: r, time-series

This seems like an obvious thing to do but I can't find a function to do it:

I have a time series of observations, say x_t, and an ARMA model specification given by AR coefficients, say \alpha_1, ..., &\alpha_p and MA coefficients \beta_1, ..., \beta_q. I want to calculate the vector of driving innovations, say e_t.

I've read the help for filter but it seems to do the opposite of what I need ( i.e. it takes innovations and the coefficients and calculates what the observations would be).

I can do this by writing out the system as Ax = Be and then using B^{-1}Ax, but that takes time for large series and I'm worried about numerical stability of the inversion.

We can generate sample observations using

```
 ts1 <- arima.sim(model=list(AR=0.5, MA=0.5), n=10)
```

How do we then find the innovations which created the observations?

Answer (score 1):

As @evilphil suggests, just use `arima()` with fixed parameters. Here is an example:

```
ts1 <- arima.sim(model=list(ar=0.5, ma=0.5), n=10)
fit <- arima(ts1, order=c(1,0,1), fixed=c(.5,.5,0))
res <- residuals(fit)
```

However, this will not actually give the innovations that were used in `arima.sim()` due to the effect of the initialization. However, for a long series, they will be close apart from the first few values.

Answer (score 0):

Think I was over-thinking this - its pretty easy to solve do this by recursion making an assumption about the white noise terms before the first observation.

Obviously this gives a loop in R.

A work-around is to use
    arima
with 
    fixed
set to your modelled parameters.